# Added layer must be an instance of class layer

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I am building a Bi-LSTM network and I have included an attention layer in it. But it is giving an error that added layer must be an instance of class layer.

Some of the libraries which I have imported are

```
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Activation, Dense, Dropout, Input, Embedding, Bidirectional, Conv1D, Flatten, GlobalMaxPooling1D, SpatialDropout1D
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
```

The attention layer class is

```
class attention(Layer):
    
    def __init__(self, return_sequences=True):
        self.return_sequences = return_sequences
        super(attention,self).__init__()
        
    def build(self, input_shape):
        
        self.W=self.add_weight(name="att_weight", shape=(input_shape[-1],1),
                               initializer="normal")
        self.b=self.add_weight(name="att_bias", shape=(input_shape[1],1),
                               initializer="zeros")
        
        super(attention,self).build(input_shape)
        
    def call(self, x):
        
        e = K.tanh(K.dot(x,self.W)+self.b)
        a = K.softmax(e, axis=1)
        output = x*a
        
        if self.return_sequences:
            return output
        
        return K.sum(output, axis=1)
```

The model looks like this

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_words, 1152, input_length=max_len, weights=[embeddings]))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(attention(return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
```

But it is giving an error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-ba5b52fe2c87> in <module>()
      1 model = Sequential()
----> 2 model.add(Embedding(max_words, 1152, input_length=max_len, weights=[embeddings]))
      3 model.add(BatchNormalization())
      4 model.add(Activation('tanh'))
      5 #model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.5))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py in add(self, layer)
    131             raise TypeError('The added layer must be '
    132                             'an instance of class Layer. '
--> 133                             'Found: ' + str(layer))
    134         self.built = False
    135         if not self._layers:

TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.embeddings.Embedding object at 0x7f0da41aec50>
```

Comment: From where do you import your `Layer`? It seems like you are mixing up `tf.keras` and `keras` libraries in this one.

Comment: I have included 'from tensorflow.keras.layers import *' So this has included all the layers

Comment: I have updated the question with the libraries imported in my model.

Comment: U import the libraries in a bad way... follow the example here also in the import please: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nyi5FWuAaRS-eypLKwWxQ_sDfv-oKaOs?usp=sharing

Comment: @MarcoCerliani I am using the same notebook as you posted, but now it gives an error `module 'keras.layers.embeddings' has no attribute 'shape`

Comment: if u use it, u don't receive errors... remove all the 'from keras' import use only tf.keras

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This documentation page](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models) states that when defining a custom `Layer`, you should use the following syntax:

```
class Linear(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units=32, input_dim=32):
        super(Linear, self).__init__()
        w_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
        self.w = tf.Variable(
            initial_value=w_init(shape=(input_dim, units), dtype="float32"),
            trainable=True,
        )
        b_init = tf.zeros_initializer()
        self.b = tf.Variable(
            initial_value=b_init(shape=(units,), dtype="float32"), trainable=True
        )

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b
```

so, your `Layer` import is technically correct. However, you initialize your model with pure `keras` layers, and that results in an error. Use the `tf.keras` functionality everywhere and the error will go, like in:

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/sequential_model

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

# Your own layer here
class AttentionCustom(layers.Layer):
     pass

model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Dense(2, activation="relu", name="layer1"),
        layers.Dense(3, activation="relu", name="layer2"),
        Attention(),
        layers.Dense(4, name="layer3"),
    ]
)
```

Comment: Where should I add tf.keras? In the custom attention layer?

Comment: No, just remove your pure `keras` imports. E.g.: `from keras.models import Model, Sequential` and 
`from keras.layers import LSTM, Activation, Dense, Dropout, Input, Embedding, Bidirectional, Conv1D, Flatten, GlobalMaxPooling1D, SpatialDropout1D` and just try importing `import tensorflow as tf`, 
`from tensorflow import keras`, 
`from tensorflow.keras import layers` only

Comment: I have marked the answer as correct. Please upvote my question too :)